# Dynamically Creating and Animation UILabel depending upon the no. of words in NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I am making a tutorial Screen where User will see random sentence from the database on the screen with animation, which will show the word from the sentence one by one. 
For example: `Hey amanda that's Nice!` It should be displayed in the center of the screen like this

```
 _________________
|                 |
|                 |
|      Hey        |
|                 |  
|     amanda      | 
|                 |
|     that's      |   
|                 |
|      nice!      |
|_________________|
```

Here's the logic what I am putting

1. Split the string using spaces
2. `individualLabelFrame = (Total width of the view)/(no. of elements in array)`
3. Create newLabel init with individualframe
4. Animate
5. Repeat

Above Logic is working properly for more than 3 words in the sentence, but I am facing problem when It comes to sentence where number of words is two or three.

i.e.

```
 _________________
|                 |
|                 |
|      Hey        |
|                 |  
|                 | 
|                 |
|     nice!       |   
|                 |
|                 |
|_________________|
```

the space between two words is too much and I am not able solve this. Same thing is happening with three words.

I know the reason its because `individualLabelFrame = (Total width of the view)/ (no. of elements in array)` so if two words then half width of both the `UILabel`'s what will be the work around for this. I don't want to put special conditions for one, two or three words.

Comment: Why do you measure width of the view if you struggle with vertical space between two words? Can you add here some code where you set individualLabelFrame?

Comment: you can use -sizeToFit after setting your split words: it should properly resize the label (don't forget to set numberOfLines to either 0 or number of words). After that you can adjust the frame if you need to (e.g. increase it).

Comment: @Szu: Becoz there is a situation where if there are two words then fontsize will be bigger so i need to keep width also bigger. I will update the question with my code

Comment: @kambala : How will I show the individual text animation if I do numberOfLines to 0 ? I did not get the logic can you explain it

Comment: @user1201239 oops, I've probably missed the animation part :) Well, you can compute size/bounding rect for each word and animate the increase of label's height accordingly. So initially you set the whole sentence to the label, set height for the first line, then increase height to the 2nd line, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Pls try with following code

```
self.dynamicString = @"Hey amanda that's Nice!";
self.dynamicString = [self.dynamicString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"\n\n"];

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(101, 50, 150,150)];
label.numberOfLines = 0;

//Use NSAttributedString
const CGFloat fontSize = 20;
UIFont *regularFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:fontSize];
//create attributes
NSDictionary *attrs = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:regularFont,NSFontAttributeName,nil];
//create the attributed string(text+attribute)
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:self.dynamicString attributes:attrs];

//Calculate height
CGSize constrainedSize = CGSizeMake(label.frame.size.width,9999);
CGRect requiredHeight = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:constrainedSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin context:nil];
CGRect newFrame = label.frame;
newFrame.size.height = requiredHeight.size.height;
label.frame = newFrame;

//Set your label text
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[label setAttributedText:attributedText];
[self.view addSubview:label];
```

Comment: Here there will be problem that my width and height will always remain same because of which I will not be able to increase the fontsize, if two words are there then font size will be bigger

Comment: Thanks it works as what expected but there is an animation  for each word in the text since we are using only one label with n no. of lines how will I do animation on it , every single word is coming from left